# Django Do Once Custom Template Tag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to create a custom template tag that only renders a block of code once, regardless of how many times the tag/partial that contains it is executed.

This is how I've implemented it, but as you can see, it's a bit hackish:

my_partial.html:

```
{% once mycontent %}
    this will only show once
{% endonce%}
```

my_template.html:

```
{% load my_tags %}
{% for i in list %}
    {% my_partial %}
{% endfor %}
```

my_tags.py:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('my_partial.html',takes_context=True)
def my_partial(context):
    return dict(arbitrary extra data)

@register.tag(name="once")
def do_once(parser, token):
    try:
        # Splitting by None == splitting by spaces.
        tag_name, var_name = token.contents.split(None, 1)
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError("%r tag requires arguments" % token.contents.split()[0])
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endonce',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return DoOnceNode(nodelist, var_name)

class DoOnceNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, nodelist, var_name):
        self.nodelist = nodelist
        self.var_name = '_do_once_'+var_name
    def render(self, context):
        request = context['request']

        # Make request.GET mutable.
        request.GET = dict(request.GET)

        if self.var_name in request.GET:
            return ''
        else:
            request.GET[self.var_name] = 1
            return self.nodelist.render(context)
```

Specifically, I'm using the request.GET dictionary as a mutable global scope. It's hackish and obviously not what the request object is designed to do, but it works.

Ideally, I'd like to use something like the context, but I found that it isn't shared between calls to this tag. i.e. `self.var_name in context` is always False, rendering it useless as a global scope.

Why isn't context shared the same way request is shared? Is there someway to make it truly shared, or is there some other object I can use to store globally accessible variables within a request?

Comment: What about request.session? It's a little less hackish. What's your use case for the 'once' template tag?

Comment: I didn't use session, because it don't want to save anything beyond the request. If I save meta data in the session, it's going to pollute my database with data that's meaningless outside of the request. My use case is to include the HTML for a modal dialog, which is normally hidden, and which may be used by several optional widgets that may or may not be used on a page. I'd like each widget to include the partial, but only do it once to avoid conflicts with the same IDs existing in different locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you need to accomplish or if your approach is indeed the best approach, but I'd suggest your look into the `forloop.first` variable before you go too far down this road.  Your approach seems awkward at best at a glance, but I could be wrong since I don't know the specifics of the situation

[django for template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Most likely you should be able to make this work to your needs, however if it falls short I'd suggest that the source for the `for` template tag (and it's `forloop` variable) would likely be very illustrative on how you might implement what you're looking to do.

Comment: The forloop is irrelevant. I only use it to show how a partial might be included multiple times. The idea is to make the tag remember the first time it is used, and disable itself thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is saving a variable within the context and checking for that in the Node's render method:

```py
class CustomNode(template.Node):
    def render(self, context: dict) -> str:
        context['already_rendered'] = context.get('already_rendered', set())

        if self.__class__ in context['already_rendered']:
            return ''

        context['already_rendered'].add(self.__class__)

        ...
```